# Displaying text on a UILabel in digital form?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, user-interface

How can we display text in digital format(seven segment display) on a UILabel similar to the way as text is displayed in Digital Clock.

Comment: You mean a seven-segment display?

Comment: Hii Andreas .......i have seen several apps that displays the data in digital format....i don know about seven segment display.

Comment: Your question can be interpreted in two ways. Either you want to print "19:49" (rather than drawing a clock). It sounds like that when you talk about a "digital clock" (as opposed to an analog clock). But I do not think that this is what you mean. I think that you want it to look like seven-segment displays, i.e. every digit is  built up by at most seven straight lines, as in this old KDE screenshot (bottomright): http://topologi-linux.sourceforge.net/files/screenshot_kde.jpg. If this is the case, you should rephrase your question so that it becomes obvious that what you want to do is to mimic

Comment: ...seven-segment displays. (Yes, this is the standard term. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven-segment_display .) I mean, any clock that prints "19:49" is a digital clock, even if the font is Comic Sans MS on a high-res LCD pixel-matrix computer screen.

Comment: thx Andreas ..........i have edited the question...i need seven segment display

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For simple you can also use Apple recommended font.

```
label.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"DBLCDTempBlack" size:60.0];
```

Please Check [this](http://discussions.apple.com/message.jspa?messageID=7523373) to find all the font supported by iPhone.

Comment: +1 Cool! It looks like it's got characters for the digits and a couple characters, but you don't get "PM" in the seven-segment form.

Comment: hey thx Razz .....it really worked......!!can you tell me one thing that why this font is not available in IB and are there some other fonts availble like this.

Comment: Link doesn't work, [this link](http://iosfonts.com) has the list of all fonts available on iOS platform.

Answer (score 3):

Simple approach: use a custom font.

Here's a `UILabel` subclass that allows you to embed custom fonts in your application: http://github.com/zynga/FontLabel

Here are a whole bunch of fonts that look like digital clocks: http://www.dafont.com/theme.php?cat=302 (be sure to read the licensing information for whatever font you choose)

Comment: thx Dave.......but i am confused how tu use it in my app.....can u explain it a level further..is there no easy way out?

Comment: can i embed the fonts mentioned in your link into this FontLabel?

Comment: @Siddharth it depends on the license of the font you choose.  Most of the ones are "free for personal use", which implies that if you want to use them commercially, you'd have to pay.  There are many other font sites that might have more permissive licenses...

Answer (score 0):

With UILabel your best bet is a font that does what you need. Most likely you will have to implement drawing part by yourself. It will not be easy what your are asking.