# Digital Clock Imaging, How is it Done?

Tags: ios, xcode, clock, digital

I'm thinking about making a digital clock app in Xcode and I'm wondering how the imaging is done. I want it to look similar to this

[image]

Do I need to create individual background images for each hour, minute, and millisecond???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use custom font for display text in your app, download digital font and use in your project

[1: displaying text on a uilabel in digital form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127390/displaying-text-on-a-uilabel-in-digital-form)

[2: digital font](http://www.fontspace.com/category/digital)